# How can I remove the promotional footer my hosting provider adds to emails?

Tags: php, phpmailer

How do I get rid of this footer in my messages?

[image]

```php
    require ('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    // Form Data
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

    $mailbody = 'Information' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL .
                'Name : ' . $name . '' . PHP_EOL .
                'E-mail Address : ' . $email . '' . PHP_EOL .
                'Message : ' . $message . '' . PHP_EOL;

    // $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'sample@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to


    $mail->setFrom('sample@gmail.com', 'WebMaster'); // Admin ID
    $mail->addAddress('sample@gmail.com', 'Admin'); // Business Owner ID
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name); // Form Submitter's ID

    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $mailbody;

    // $mail->send();

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using free hosting so you cannot remove this.

This advertisement is automatically attached by the hosting providers as you use their hosting.
Its better to use a paid hosting or try free trials of GOOGLE CLOUD/AWS/MICROSOFT AZURE

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider is able to do this because you're doing this:

```
// $mail->isSMTP();
```

By commenting out this line, PHPMailer falls back to sending via PHP's `mail()` function. This way of sending sends through a local mail server without any encryption, and your provider is exploiting that fact in order to inject the footer you're seeing.

If you use a secure transport, such as by using SMTP with TLS to gmail, your provider is denied that opportunity because they can't see (let alone interfere with) your messages, and the footer would not appear.

However, its likely that you commented out that line because your SMTP configuration wasn't working, and that's likely to be because your hosting provider blocks outbound SMTP, which is very common, especially at the low end.